# the right usage of Heridity in Java and the private attribute issue?

Tags: java

I need to code a programm and have some issues doing so:

Super-Class:

```
public class Kunde {
    private String name;
    private String adresse;
    private double marge;
    private int nummer;

    public Kunde(String name, String adresse, int nummer) {
        this.name = name;
        this.adresse = adresse;
        this.nummer= nummer;
        marge = 2;


    }

    public void print() {
        System.out.println("\nKunde: "+name);
        System.out.println("Adresse: "+adresse);
        System.out.println("Kundennummer: "+nummer);
        System.out.println("Marge: "+marge);
    }

    public double getMarge() {
        return marge;
    }

    public void setMarge(double marge) {
        this.marge = marge;
    }

    public int getNummer() {
        return nummer;
    }
}
```

Main-Class:

```
        public class Main {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
        Kunde k1 = new Geschaeftskunde("ABC AG", "Weg 3", 100,"CHE.123");
        Kunde k2 = new Privatkunde("Hans Müller","Nebenstrasse 2", 101);
        k1.print();
        k2.print();
 }
```

For the Kunde k1 an error occurs: "The constructor Geschaeftskunde is undefined"

But i actually initialized the constructor as followed:

```
       public class Geschaeftskunde extends Kunde {
    private String uid;
    public Geschaeftskunde (String name, String adresse, int nummer) {
        super(name,adresse,nummer); 

}



   public String getUid() {
        return uid;
    }
         public void print() {
            System.out.println("UID: "+uid);

    }
}
```

In the same way I initialized the constructor for Kunde k2:

```
public class Privatkunde extends Kunde {
public Privatkunde (String name, String adresse, int nummer) {
super(name,adresse,nummer);

}
}
```

And for this class this error surprisingly doesnt occur?

Question:

How can i use and change the attribute marge in the classes Geschaeftskunde und Privatkunde when its set on private?

I know that you can use public methodes with that attribute so is the code: "super.setMarge(x);" the right attempt in solving this problem?

Comment: `Geschaeftskunde()` takes 3 arguments but you call it with 4.

Comment: Right thats the clue. I just added String uid in the constructor and the error is gone. Thank you :)

Comment: How can i use and change the attribute marge in the classes Geschaeftskunde und Privatkunde when its set on private?  For GK it should be 2 and for PK 2.5?                                                                                        I know that you can use public methodes with that attribute so is the code: "super.setMarge(x);" the right attempt in solving this problem?

Answer (score 0):

The compiler error is due to `Geschaeftskunde` taking 3 arguments while you call it with 4.
Regarding `marge` you need to use `setMarge(x)` and `getMarge()`. The `super` is not necessary since `Geschaeftskunde`/`Privatkunde` inherit the public methods.
Fixed constructor for `Geschaeftskunde`:

```
public Geschaeftskunde (String name, String adresse, int nummer, String uid){
    super(name,adresse,nummer); 
    this.uid = uid;
    this.setMarge(2);
}
```

`Privatkunde`would be similar.